# Cannot access specific value of a hash - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello i have been trying to access the token value of the following hash with no avail

```
email.to[{:token=>"example", :host=>"HOSTNAME here", :email=>"example email", :full=>"example@email.com", :name=>nil}]
```

does it not `email.to[:token]` give me the value of token?

when i do that i get this

`TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):`

if not what is the correct way to do it. Is there any point in doing a loop when i just need one value?

Comment: `email.to` actually returns an array containing a single hash. Try `email.to.first[:token]`

Comment: @MrYoshiji this worked thanks! but why do i have to put `.first` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*email.to* method returns an Array that contains a Hash

```
[{:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}]
```

so you have to specify the index of an element in that array first

```
email.to[0][:a]
```

or

```
email.to.first[:a]
```

In order to access the Hash without an index, `email.to` method would have to return a Hash and not an Array type. So it would have to be something likes this

```
def to
  {:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}
end
```